# Hide and Unhide button programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I am trying to hide a button while a text field is empty then show it when the user starts typing.

I tried making an outlet for the button and in viewDidLoad used a while loop to implement the outlet for the button and the text field. It did not work, i been searching around but most of the code are objective-C so i have a hard time translating it to swift.

Is it even possible to hide a button while a text field is empty?

Swift preferred

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: Have you read the documentation? A combination of "detect change in textview" and "make button invisible" should do the trick

Comment: Add listeners for TextDelegates. You will then be notified when user starts typing text, then you can hide/unhide based on text input.

Comment: And don't overlook to link the IBOutlet with the related UI elements within IB (storyboard editor).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use  UITextFieldDelegate to hide and show button.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController,UITextFieldDelegate  //set delegate to class 

@IBOutlet var txtValue: UITextField             //create a textfile variable 

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    txtValue.delegate = self 
   YourButton.hidden=false;

            //set delegate to textfile
}


func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField!)
 {    //delegate method

   YourButton.hidden=true;
}

func textFieldShouldEndEditing(textField: UITextField!) -> Bool {  //delegate method
    return false

}

func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField!) -> Bool {   //delegate method
  textField.resignFirstResponder()

    return true
}
```

May be it will help you.

Comment: Thank you, really simple to use :)

Comment: If my answer is helful to you mark it as answer or give me upvotes

Comment: One problem, you never unhide the button, it'll always be hidden once typing starts. Which I presume is bad b/c then the user has no way to reverse the process.

Also this is a "meh" answer. A much better way is to use ReactiveCocoa and bind the hidden state of the button to the text signal of the textfield and dynamically hide it.

Answer (score 0):

Try This Code:

```
func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range:NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool 
{
    text = text.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet())
    var strMsg: String = textView.text.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet())
    if strMsg.length() > 0 || text.length() > 0 
    {
         self.YourButton.alpha = 1.0
         self.YourButton.enabled = true
    }
    else 
    {
         self.YourButton.alpha = 0.5
         self.YourButton.enabled = false
    }
    return true
}
```

Comment: thanks for taking time to answer my question but i proceeded with  @Bhumica answer since it was simple but i am sure your code works as well, maybe for other stuff :)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you have to hide button by using this code.

```
btn1.hidden = YES;
```

After Assign UITextFieldDelegate to file owner, also implement the same delegate in .h file

after than when you start writing writing some text on textfield you this code.

```
-(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
     NSString *newString = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];

     [self updateTextLabelsWithText: newString];

     return YES;
}

-(void)updateTextLabelsWithText:(NSString *)string
 {
    [myLabel setText:string];
 }
```

When textfield text run use

```
btn1.hidden = NO;
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for posting but as i mentioned i have a hard time translating to swift